# Loading serialized class from file, when class has changed (Java/Android)

Tags: java, android

I have found many answers on how to write/read a serialized class to a file, and have successfully implemented it into my Android app, I have however hit an issue with expanding the functionality of my app.

For example if I have carClass:

```
String make;
String model;
```

I then save that to my save file and whenever I load it the stored values are ok :)

But when I then try to expand the class to include something else i.e. color:

```
String make;
String model;
String color;
```

When the app loads the file, it tries to cast the object into the new class, and as the loaded object does not have 'color' it fails to load the save file.

How do I overcome this?  At the moment every time I add new stuff to my app, user's save files are effectively invalid and they have to start again, which is not a good user experience!

Comment: Create a new class with all attributes. Load all old objects, and from that data you an create instances of your new class.

Comment: @Pphoenix Isn't it much easier to just declare a `serialVersionUID`? See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501941/loading-serialized-class-from-file-when-class-has-changed-java-android/25502046#25502046)

Comment: @bcsb1001 Can you still read a file with the old class definition? I was pretty sure that the file would not be read by an ObjectInputStream. And what value do new variables get?

Comment: @Pphoenix They get their default value (the same given from default constructor) and yes, you can still read it, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `static final long serialVersionUID` in your class. This will make it forwards/backwards compatible e.g.

```
String make;
String model;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
```

is compatible with

```
String make;
String model;
String color;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
```

as long as you keep the value of `serialVersionUID` the same. Docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) for android, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for normal Java.

Comment: I will try this tonight! The best thing about your answer is no major refactor is needed :)

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Just another quick question, you said to keep the serialVersionUID the same, but in the documentation it says _'If you declare a serialVersionUID, you should increment it each time your class changes incompatibly with the previous version. Typically this is when you add, change or remove a non-transient field.'_.  So should I increment and if so how? Does the L always stay as it is and I just increment the digit? e.g. 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L?

Comment: @killzusall I believe what you are doing is **not** incompatible, and therefore doesn't require incrementing (will test this in a sec), but if you _must_ increment it, just do 0L, 1L, etc. like you said. All the `L` means is that it is a `long` value, not the default of `int`.

Comment: Just tested, and incrementing the `serialVersionUID` will make it impossible to read previous forms of your class without `InvalidClassException`. So, **leave `serialVersionUID` the same unless you want to invalidate all previous forms of the class.**

Comment: Tried it last night and it worked great!  Thanks again bcsb1001